# 3rd party framework for creating automatic updater module

Tags: c#, windows-services, automatic-updates

I have a window service which is installed by user and setup to run under context of domain administrator account. I am not storing these credentials anywhere.

Reinstalling parallel service will not be a solution for me, as I will not have those credentials again and other configuration which user done while installation.

I want to create an automatic update service to update my main service.

**I want to know is there any 3rd party framework available for me to do this task?**

**Wybuild** will not work for me as it will update only service running in local system, **click once** not suited for window service.

Please suggest me some 3rd party framework, if its available.

Thanks in advance.